# How to parse links and escape html entities?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, html-escape-characters

I have some user provided content that I want to render.

Obviously the content should be escaped, rails does this by default. However I also want to parse the text so that urls are presented as links.

There is an `auto_link` helper which does just that. However no matter what order I do this in I can't get the desired result.

Take content:

```
content                                             
  => "<img src=\"foo\" />\\r\\n\\r\\nhttp://google.com"
```

If this is escaped, because the slashes in the url are escaped, auto_link will not work:

```
Rack::Utils.escape_html(content)                    
  => "&lt;img src=&quot;foo&quot; &#x2F;&gt;\\r\\n\\r\\nhttp:&#x2F;&#x2F;google.com"
```

If I use auto_link first obviously the link will be escaped. Additionally auto_link strips unwanted content rather than escaping. If a script tag is present in the input I want it escaped not removed.

```
auto_link(content)                                  
  => "<img src=\"foo\" />\\r\\n\\r\\n<a href=\"http://google.com\">http://google.com</a>"
```

Any idea how to do get the desired output?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you saving content to the db? Are you doing something to escape the content before saving it? Do you have the option of sanitising the content and saving as pure html?

Comment: It's just a text field in the db. Rather not escape before saving as other non html views may be used in the future. Even if I could escape on save rather than render I would have to solve the same problem as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was ditching auto_link, letting Rack escape my content server side and then parsed the links out of the text on the client side using https://github.com/gabrielizaias/urlToLink

```
$('p').urlToLink();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could strip out all the escaped whitespace characters with `content.gsub!(/\\./, "")`. Then you'll be able to use `auto_link`.

Comment: Would this not leave it as http:google.com? Don't think that would work with auto_link...

Comment: The result will be `"<img src=\"foo\" />http://google.com"`. The `gsub` is replacing this pattern: "\." Whitespace characters use a backwards slash and a character. Your URL will be safe as ULRs use a forward slash.

Comment: OK, I misread. That doesn't help. I want to preserve white space, and escape html/script injections

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with:

```
auto_link(h(content))
```